# Swift *.stringsdict returns wrong key for polish value

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm doing polish localization in iOS project and in my *Localizable.stringsdict* file I got key:

```
<key>general_people_number</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>%#@value@</string>
    <key>value</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>d</string>
        <key>zero</key>
        <string>%d osób</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>%d osoba</string>
        <key>few</key>
        <string>%d osoby</string>
        <key>many</key>
        <string>%d osób</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%d other</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now when I'm trying to use:

```
String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("general_people_number", comment: ""), 9)
```

The output is:

```
9 other
```

So the output value is for "other" type though if I get rules at this page from Swift documentation:
http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html
For "9" it should return the key for "many" types.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not an iOS dev, but perhaps the equation used where `n=9` doesn't match your keys. Firstly, that CLDR link shows no zero form in Polish. Secondly, I've seen rule sets in some systems where Polish has only One, Few and Other. Any way to check what exact rule is used internally to produce the key from `n`?

Comment: Same project, same code, same Localizable.stringsdict file when simulated with polish language via Xcode runs flawlessly and acts properly with n=9 and any other parameter. Moreover, we have deployed it to AppStore and it runs on iphones as it should. I don't know any other way than setting different translations on each rule to see which rule is used

Answer (score 0):

Well I have figured it out...

**The problem is probably caused by AppCode**, some weird bug. It occures when I add

```
-AppleLanguages (pl)
```

to *Program Arguments* in *Edit Configuration*. **It does not occure when I run my app via Xcode.**

In AppCode I have tried as well:

```
-AppleLanguages (pl)
-AppleLanguages (pol)
-AppleLanguages (Polish)
```

with same output. Funny thing is when I run

```
-AppleLanguages(pl)
```

without space between the app runs in English language so it means those arguments actually work and pick the proper *Localizable.stringsdict* just have bug with this plural rules...

**If anyone have fix, explanation to this I would be grateful** because right now I don't have any way to run my app via AppCode and test different languages.